# Screen recording software that creates Flash video

Tags: windows, software-rec, screen-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best software for desktop recording?](https://superuser.com/questions/6801/what-is-the-best-software-for-desktop-recording)

I would like to create some tutorial videos on my PHP framework, therefore I'm looking for a good screen recorder application (Windows 7). I've used Camstudio, unfortunately it crashes my local Apache when using the Flash uploader. Any suggestions?

It would be cool if it could implement audio / show a graphical indicator when clicking the mouse, any ideas? Ah yes, it should be able to create flash video.

Comment: Although Flash is very rare. Jing creates flash based video, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of gamers use [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/).

So you might want to take a look into that. I don't know whether it can produce flash videos - although I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

I think we're mostly missing the point--which is that in order to play video content online, that content does not necessarily need to be in Flash video (`.flv`) format.

Most YouTube/Vimeo players are actually playing back H.264 underneath the Flash layer.

You shouldn't worry about using a screen recorder that "creates flash video"--rather, just get something that outputs a standardized container and codec, and *then* worry about how you're going to display that to your viewer.

Not much really uses FLV except Adobe's own Flash tools. I'd look into the open-source [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player) and take note of what formats it can display (H.264, MP4, as well as FLV).

I think you already have enough [resources for finding screen recording software](https://superuser.com/questions/6801/what-is-the-best-software-for-desktop-recording).